# .Net Lib\Wrapper that would clear differences between ATI and Nvidea APIs for counting on GPU?

Tags: .net, cpu, gpu, nvidia

I want to use GPU for counting purposes. I need it to fall on to CPU if no GPU found and provide me with unified api. (interested in any .net for example №4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenCL.net](http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/OpenCL.NET/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any library that stable and ready to production. Maybe someone can correct me. But there are many developed.

Check:

[OpenCL.NET](http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Default.aspx) / [CUDA.NET](http://blogs.hoopoe-cloud.com/index.php/category/cudanet/)

[brahma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/) / [additional info](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/)

[Microsoft's Accelerator](http://connect.microsoft.com/acceleratorv2):  Articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/satnam_singh/archive/2010/01/11/a-c-implementation-of-a-convolver-using-accelerator-for-gpgpu-and-multicore-targets-using-linq-operators.aspx , http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/)

C$ - http://cbucks.codeplex.com/

Conflux - http://bitbucket.org/conflux/conflux